# How to get other field base on the max record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a temp table, storing the customer details, I want to query the data which group by the CustomerNo and show the ImagePath if IsDefault is set 1.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(ID varchar(100), CustomerNo varchar(10), IsDefault int, ImagePath varchar(100), ViewCount int)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT '1', 'AC1234', 1, 'xxx1.jpg', 12 UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx2.jpg', 42 UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx3.jpg', 15 UNION ALL
SELECT '4', 'AC1235', 0, 'xxx4.jpg', 16 UNION ALL
SELECT '5', 'AC1236', 1, 'xxx5.jpg', 13 UNION ALL
SELECT '6', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx6.jpg', 56 UNION ALL
SELECT '7', 'AC1235', 1, 'xxx7.jpg', 17

SELECT * FROM #Temp
SELECT CustomerNo, MAX(IsDefault) as IsDefault, Sum(ViewCount) as ViewCount FROM #Temp
GROUP BY CustomerNo

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Result:

```
CustomerNo IsDefault   ViewCount
---------- ----------- -----------
AC1234     1           125
AC1235     1           33
AC1236     1           13
```

Can I have a result like this (Show the ImagePath if "IsDefault" = 1)?

```
CustomerNo IsDefault   ViewCount   ImagePath
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
AC1234     1           125         xxx1.jpg
AC1235     1           33          xxx4.jpg
AC1236     1           13          xxx5.jpg
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: What if there are several rows with `Max(IsDefault)`?

Comment: Suppose same CustomerNo will only have have 1 record has IsDefault = 1

Comment: then remove `GROUP BY` and select by `WHERE IsDefault = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one record have the IsDefault flag to 1, this will do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (
    ID varchar(100)
  , CustomerNo varchar(10)
  , IsDefault int
  , ImagePath varchar(100)
  , ViewCount int
);

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT '1', 'AC1234', 1, 'xxx1.jpg', 12 UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx2.jpg', 42 UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx3.jpg', 15 UNION ALL
SELECT '4', 'AC1235', 0, 'xxx4.jpg', 16 UNION ALL
SELECT '5', 'AC1236', 1, 'xxx5.jpg', 13 UNION ALL
SELECT '6', 'AC1234', 0, 'xxx6.jpg', 56 UNION ALL
SELECT '7', 'AC1235', 1, 'xxx7.jpg', 17
;

with CustomerReport (CustomerNo, ViewCount) as 
     (SELECT t.CustomerNo, Sum(t.ViewCount) ViewCount 
        FROM #Temp t
       GROUP BY t.CustomerNo)
Select q1.CustomerNo, q1.ViewCount 
       , (Select ImagePath
            from #Temp
           where #Temp.CustomerNo = q1.CustomerNo
             and #Temp.IsDefault = 1) ImgPath
  from CustomerReport q1
;

drop table #temp
;
```

AFAIK, you need MS-SQL 2008+ to get support for the CTE syntax.